# Laravel Eloquent Query for Double Entry Journal

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, accounting

I have a table `journals` having columns transaction_id, type(receipt or payment), debit and credit columns for amount, account_id relation with `accounts` table

the records can be multiple receipt or payment entries, and an opposite entry to record sum of these multiple entries matching transaction_id
if entries are type receipt column credit should have amount else column debit should have amount.

i want to retrieve results as following.
get all journals, each row should have opposite row columns,
rows columns should be like this.
transaction_id, type, amount(debit or credit), credit_id(based on entry type, from journal or opposite journal), debit_id(based on entry type, from journal or opposite journal matching transaction_id)

```
$accounts = DB::select("
SELECT 
    a.id as account_id, 
    a.title as accountTitle,
    j1.type as type,
    CASE 
        WHEN j1.type = 'cashReceipt' THEN j1.credit
        ELSE j1.debit
    END AS amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN j1.type = 'cashReceipt' THEN j1.account_id
        ELSE j2.account_id
    END AS credit_id,
    a_credit.title as credit_account_title,
    CASE 
        WHEN j1.type = 'cashPayment' THEN j1.account_id
        ELSE j2.account_id
    END AS debit_id,
    a_debit.title as debit_account_title,
    j1.narration
FROM 
    accounts a
JOIN 
    journals j1 ON a.id = j1.account_id
JOIN 
    journals j2 ON j1.transaction_id = j2.transaction_id
JOIN
    accounts a_credit ON a_credit.id = CASE 
        WHEN j1.type = 'cashReceipt' THEN j1.account_id
        ELSE j2.account_id
    END
JOIN
    accounts a_debit ON a_debit.id = CASE 
        WHEN j1.type = 'cashPayment' THEN j1.account_id
        ELSE j2.account_id
    END
WHERE 
    (j1.type = 'cashReceipt' AND j2.type = 'cashPayment')
    OR 
    (j1.type = 'cashPayment' AND j2.type = 'cashReceipt')
```

");

but not returning rows as expected, number of rows are 35640, but result was 7640

i have rows like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided appears to be an attempt to retrieve journal entries with their corresponding opposite entries. It seems like you want to get all journal entries that have a matching opposite entry based on the **transaction_id**. However, there are a few issues in your query that could lead to unexpected results:

Joining **j1** and **j2** without distinguishing between debit and credit entries can create a Cartesian product, resulting in more rows than you expect.
The conditions in your **WHERE** clause may not be restrictive enough to match entries correctly.
Here's an updated query that should help you retrieve the desired results:

```
SELECT 
j1.transaction_id,
j1.type,
CASE 
    WHEN j1.type = 'receipt' THEN j1.credit
    WHEN j1.type = 'payment' THEN j1.debit
END AS amount,
CASE 
    WHEN j1.type = 'receipt' THEN j1.credit_id
    WHEN j1.type = 'payment' THEN j1.debit_id
END AS credit_id,
CASE 
    WHEN j1.type = 'receipt' THEN j1.debit_id
    WHEN j1.type = 'payment' THEN j1.credit_id
END AS debit_id
FROM journals j1
WHERE j1.type = 'receipt' OR j1.type = 'payment'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
j2.transaction_id,
j2.type,
CASE 
    WHEN j2.type = 'receipt' THEN j2.credit
    WHEN j2.type = 'payment' THEN j2.debit
END AS amount,
CASE 
    WHEN j2.type = 'receipt' THEN j2.credit_id
    WHEN j2.type = 'payment' THEN j2.debit_id
END AS credit_id,
CASE 
    WHEN j2.type = 'receipt' THEN j2.debit_id
    WHEN j2.type = 'payment' THEN j2.credit_id
END AS debit_id
FROM journals j2
WHERE j2.type = 'receipt' OR j2.type = 'payment';
```

In this query, use a **UNION** ALL to combine the records from the **journals** table.separate the logic for **receipt** and **payment** entries and ensure that retrieve the corresponding **credit_id** and **debit_id** based on the entry type. This should help you get the correct results.

**Make sure your data model and naming conventions match this query for it to work correctly.**

Comment: i have added an image of database records. receipt or payment type can have multiple entries with different account_id, sum if its receipts or payments is recorded in 1 entry matching transaction_id, my question is i want to get all rows and account_id from matching the opposite row, excluding opposite row from records

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to retrieve all rows from the **journals** table while matching each row with its opposite entry based on the **transaction_id**. You also want to exclude the opposite rows from the result set. To achieve this, you can use a self-join and a subquery.

```
SELECT 
j1.transaction_id,
j1.type,
j1.amount,
j1.account_id AS debit_account_id,
j2.account_id AS credit_account_id
FROM journals j1
INNER JOIN journals j2 ON j1.transaction_id = j2.transaction_id
WHERE j1.type = 'payment' AND j2.type = 'receipt'
OR j1.type = 'receipt' AND j2.type = 'payment';
```

Comment: well this worked, but had only 1 issue, producing 2 rows for each transaction_id, the first row had same ids for debit_account_id and credit_account_id, and the second row had different ids, i added j1.account_id <> j2.account_id and it returned rows with different account ids,

Comment: it has to be different ids in each row, because in double entry accounting we cannot have same account_id on both debit_id and credit_id, also i want to join related account title with debit_id and credit_id

Comment: SELECT 
    j1.transaction_id,
    j1.type,
    j1.amount,
    j1.account_id AS debit_account_id,
    j2.account_id AS credit_account_id
FROM journals j1
INNER JOIN journals j2 ON j1.transaction_id = j2.transaction_id
WHERE (j1.type = 'payment' AND j2.type = 'receipt')
   OR (j1.type = 'receipt' AND j2.type = 'payment')
   AND j1.account_id <> j2.account_id;

Comment: SELECT 
    j1.transaction_id,
    j1.type,
    j1.amount,
    j1.account_id AS debit_account_id,
    j2.account_id AS credit_account_id,
    a_debit.title AS debit_account_title,
    a_credit.title AS credit_account_title
FROM journals j1
INNER JOIN journals j2 ON j1.transaction_id = j2.transaction_id
INNER JOIN accounts a_debit ON a_debit.id = j1.account_id
INNER JOIN accounts a_credit ON a_credit.id = j2.account_id
WHERE (j1.type = 'payment' AND j2.type = 'receipt')
   OR (j1.type = 'receipt' AND j2.type = 'payment')
   AND j1.account_id <> j2.account_id;